# ¿Cómo sumo columnas con Awk?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Tengo el siguiente archivo csv:

```
,2019 - October,,2019 - September,,2019 - August,
,Agricultural,Industrial,Agricultural,Industrial,Agricultural,Industrial
Toronto,86746,382958,55833,348182,49313,355977
Montreal,70718,605909,22084,549823,23428,641181
Calgary,231493,1420226,114937,1249378,114243,1189979
TOTAL,388957,2409093,192853,2147384,186984,2187137
```

Tengo que hacer un script para mostrar la información del archivo de esta manera:

```
2  388957  388957
3  2409093  2409093
.. ......   ....
```

Por ejemplo, en la primera línea, el número 2 corresponde al número de columna (la visualización comienza en la columna B, visto el archivo csv desde Excel), el siguiente número corresponde a la suma de las filas 3 a 5 de la columna B, y el último corresponde al número la fila TOTAL (el último valor de la columna B). La segunda línea es la misma, pero se hace con la columna C, y así sucesivamente desde la columna B hasta la columna G.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto en Bash?

He intentado hacer esto, pero no funciona (sé que tengo cosas mal):

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUTFILE="/media/exports.csv"
FIELD=2
COUNT=`sed 's/[^,]//g' $INPUTFILE | wc -c`; let "COUNT+=1"
while [ "$FIELD" -lt "$COUNT" ]; do
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";sum=0}{if(NR>=3&&NR<=5)sum=sum+$FIELD}END{print$FIELD,sum, (tail -1), "\n"
  }' /media/exports.csv
  let "FIELD+=1"
done
```

Al ejecutar este script, la información se muestra así, repitiéndose el mismo resultado muchas veces:

```
TOTAL,388957,2409093,192853,2147384,186984,2187137 0 -1
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que estás usando Awk parcialmente, ¿por qué no usarlo del todo?

```
awk -F, 'NR>=3 && $1 != "TOTAL" {
             for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {sum[i] += $i}
         }
         $1 == "TOTAL" {
             for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {tot[i] = $i}
         }
         END {for (i in sum) {print i, sum[i], tot[i]}}' fichero
```

Es decir, ve acumulando en `sum[i]` la suma de la columna `i` y en `tot[i]` el valor de cada columna de la línea cuyo primer valor es "TOTAL". Finalmente, imprime.

Con tu fichero:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>=3 && $1 != "TOTAL" {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {sum[i] += $i}} $1 == "TOTAL" {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) tot[i] = $i} END {for (i in sum) {print i, sum[i], tot[i]}}' fichero
2 388957 388957
3 2409093 2409093
4 192854 192853
5 2147383 2147384
6 186984 186984
7 2187137 2187137
```